# How to find AppxManifest.xml file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, manifest

I read the article of "How Visual Studio generates an app package manifest" here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/generate-package-manifest.

It mentioned about two types of manifest package:

- Package.appxmanifest
- AppxManifest.xml

The second is generated by the Visual Studio build process and is based on the information in the Package.appxmanifest file.

I am using visual studio 2019; I added app.manifest into my project through project->add new item. After building my project, i do not have any file AppxManifest.xml as being mentioned in the article above.

Could you please explain me why and how to find out this AppxManifest.xml because i need to add some requirements of devices (ex. microphone) for my application (c#).

Finally, thanks you so much for your help and your kindness.

Cordially

Answer (score 0):

This page shows you how to create a basic package manifest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-create-a-basic-package-manifest

We could use a text editor, create a file (which will contain XML) and name it Package.appxmanifest instead of adding the app.manifest. If you want to add some requirements of devices for your application, you can refer to this page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-in-a-package-manifest

Comment: Thanks for guidance.
I  dit it already (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-in-a-package-manifest). 
But when i run my application, it does not require the devices  which are required like <Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>
  <DeviceCapability Name="webcam"/>
</Capabilities>
Could you please tell me how my application works with this file manifest.xml?
Thanks you so much for your kindness.

Comment: This page tells you how to enable device capabilities. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh768221(v=win.10)